# Reserved Instances with scope Region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

I am querying Reserved Instances using Amazon's Java SDK. I am getting all reserved Reserved Instances except the one with scope as "Region".

I have raised an issue on Amazon's Java SDK code. After analysis it is found that Amazon service itself [is not returning those Reserved Instances](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1080#issuecomment-289496779).

Can anyone offer advice on how to obtain information about Reserved Instances with a scope of `Region`?

Comment: The [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) has a [describe-reserved-instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-reserved-instances.html) API call that includes a field for `Scope`. Could you try that and see whether it is returning the information you expect?

Comment: John, aws cli is returning reserved instances with scope "Region". I tried with(filter with "Region" scope) and without filters, both commands are returning RI with scope region.

Comment: Just to clarify... Are you saying that the AWS CLI returns the correct information, but the same API call via the Java SDK returns *different* information (that is, some RIs missing)?

Comment: Yes. Reserved Instances having scope as Region are missing.

Comment: Worst case, raise a bug on the [Github project](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java).

Comment: I had raised an [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1080#issuecomment-289496779). After analyzing wire trace, Kyle mentioned that Aws service which is serving the request is not returning expected result.

Comment: That's very strange, because the AWS CLI is probably making the same API call. The information returned should be the same, even though they came from different API clients.